# xauth not creating .Xauthority file

Tags: linux, ssh, xauth

When I ssh into a headless Linux Mint 17 system, it doesn't create update / create an .Xauthority file.

Moreover, when I run `xauth` I get the reply:

```
marty@N40L ~ $ xauth
xauth:  file /home/marty/.Xauthority does not exist
Using authority file /home/marty/.Xauthority
xauth>exit
marty@N40L ~ $ xauth
xauth:  file /home/marty/.Xauthority does not exist
Using authority file /home/marty/.Xauthority
xauth>
```

It doesn't create the file.

EDIT:

When I connect monitor, then log in locally, the file is created but when I try to add an entry (because my SSH doesn't do it for me):

```
marty@N40L ~ $ xauth list
N40L/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  34eee3b15cdb281021502d40dfba1cf2
localhost.localdomain/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  34eee3b15cdb281021502d40dfba1cf2
marty@N40L ~ $ ls -d .X*
-rw------- 1 marty marty 115 Sep  3 12:03 .Xauthority
marty@N40L ~ $ xauth generate $DISPLAY .
PuTTY X11 proxy: wrong authorisation protocol attemptedxauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display "localhost:10.0".
```

Incidentally, doing a `netstat --listen` shows the port listening:

```
tcp 0 0 localhost:6010 *:* LISTEN
```

AGH, more info. I logged out of the X session on the server, and now the .Xauthority file has disappeared. It seems the file is ONLY there when logged in locally.
Can anyone tell me why, or how I can fix this?

NEW DEVELOPMENT:

I created a virgin user on the system called "test". I then logged in, and without ANY other commands, ran xeyes. Which worked! So it's ONLY the user "marty" that cannot xforward. How do I copy the settings from test to marty?

Comment: Did you tell it to create the file? `ssh -X` enables X11 forwarding.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Putty on Windows, setup for forwarding (works on connecting to another Mint server). But the file is not created, so I thought I'd add it manually, xauth doesn't create it manually either.

Comment: Local Xwindows creates the .Xauthority file, but Putty SSH session doesn't. Even though it shows it listening for the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out that it wasn't the system, by adding a test user (which x forwarding worked "out the box"), I thought I'd start copying the .bash* startup files across to virginise the "broken" user.

None of the files were different, so next I deleted the users .ssh directory. When I ssh'd in, it moaned about "Server refused our key", but I could log in using password. Once logged in, I could x forward perfectly.

I'll now try to setup the key again and see if I can get that working too. Then it'll be back to normal.

Answer (score 77):

Just to report, I did have a similar problem. But in my case I just follow [those steps](http://justaix.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/createrebuild-new-xauthority-file.html):

Follow these steps to create a `$HOME/.Xauthority` file.

Log in as user and confirm that you are in the user's home directory.

```
# Rename the existing .Xauthority file by running the following command
mv .Xauthority old.Xauthority 

# xauth with complain unless ~/.Xauthority exists
touch ~/.Xauthority

# only this one key is needed for X11 over SSH 
xauth generate :0 . trusted 

# generate our own key, xauth requires 128 bit hex encoding
xauth add ${HOST}:0 . $(xxd -l 16 -p /dev/urandom)

# To view a listing of the .Xauthority file, enter the following 
xauth list
```

After that there are no more problems with `.Xauthority` file since then.

Thanks and credits to [srinivasan](https://www.blogger.com/profile/01059131040463397910).

Comment: in my case, I had an environment variable XAUTHORITY pointing to somewhere else (a careless mistake), using this [http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2011/11/01/dealing-with-xauth-error-in-locking-authority-file-errors/] thread I was able to discover this and resolve the error. Using `strace xauth`, it pointed out the incorrect path specified in the variable. I should also add that I was getting locking errors aswel, amongst others

Comment: In my case, I only had to do step 1 to 3. Step 4 and 5 actually made it not work.

Comment: I have to do `xauth generate :0 . trusted` after every command as `user` to open a display as `root`. Can I make it fix?

Comment: `xhost +` helped to open x-apps as `root`.

Comment: step 3 gives me the error: `xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".`

Comment: Many postings say not to run 'xhost +' due to security implications.

Comment: @simpleuser - I had the same issue, but it worked. Still I asked the question one more time: https://superuser.com/questions/1607526/ssh-x-to-machine-without-any-monitor-to-open-a-gui

Comment: @simpleuser replacing :0 with $DISPLAY worked for me as I use XQUARTZ as an X11 server on my mac laptop

Comment: After this I still have issues. Whenever I run mpirun I get "Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1". If I remove it I go back to "No protocol specified".

Comment: For those with `xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".`, maybe your Xorg is running in another display port... check if `$DISPLAY` environment variable helps.

Comment: When I run with $DISPLAY I have the following error: `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication`
`xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display "localhost:11.0".`

Comment: check this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110558/su-with-error-x11-connection-rejected-because-of-wrong-authentication#118295

Comment: @ton: Any idea what is the root cause of this issue? it happens to my Gitlab server frequently (every month) and suddenly my services goes down

Comment: @Amir, as a gitlab-server is just a webapp, does no seems to make any sense Xorg to cause it to be down, I do suggest to you check how the service is setup. But in gitlab-runners it can be a problem depending on what kind of projects dependencies you are building. Probably specific to a project repo CI build. You need to check for example if the project is recreating the xauth setup inside a new container that is not so simple to integrate with host Xorg because the libs can be in different versions. Anyway it's very hard to tip without know more about your context.

Answer (score 14):

Under root privileges open `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and uncomment the following lines if they are commented:

> X11Forwarding yes
>
> X11DisplayOffset 10
>
> X11UseLocalhost yes

Then logout and login again with `-X` flag in `ssh`. You do not have to set or unset `DISPLAY` environment variable.

Answer (score 6):

Just to complement the excellent [ton](https://superuser.com/users/285608/ton)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/941244/227582).

I have once had exactly the same problem because my home directory had become 100% full. Upon connection, `ssh` created an empty `~/.Xauthority` and was unable to write any single entry to it (so that `xauth list` had always produced an empty output).

So I suggest one always checks the free space (e. g.: `df -h`) and verifies that `xauth generate` and `xauth add` have indeed had any effect (`xauth list`).

Answer (score 4):

Found another potential cause of xauth not creating the .Xauthority file by following a couple of the answers above.  Should become immediately obvious if you are following [Ton's answer](https://superuser.com/a/941244/17502):

```
$ touch ~/.Xauthority
touch: cannot touch ‘/nethome/jdoe/.Xauthority’: Disk quota exceeded
```

The above will happen if you exceed the "number of files" quota for your user.  If you exceed the space quota, you will likely see that error message at a different step.  Or, to test if its a space disk quota issue, type:

```
echo "hello, world" > ~/hello.txt
```

If the `echo` gives you a `Disk quota exceeded` message, then you know that you are using too much space in your home directory (as opposed to too many files or inodes).

Solution in either case?  Clean up your home directory!

Answer (score 2):

Moving the `.ssh` directory out of the way made X forwarding work for me.

Through process of elimination, I found a file in ~/.ssh that was called "rc", and contained:

```
echo "Wecome to $(hostname), $(whoami)"
```

I never created this, and have no idea where it came from.  Removing it fixed the issue, and my `authorized_keys`, `known_hosts`, and key files can all stay intact.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this same issue on two servers that were technically sister nodes. Pain in my tail, as I couldn't figure out what was different. Turns out the /home directory was full, so .Xauthority files couldn't populate properly. Once I located the file(s) taking up too much space and purged them, new .Xauthority files were created properly.

Answer (score 2):

Here goes another answer, which I would have liked to find (handling the case of forwarding from a VM host to its VM guest):

There may be certain VM images (in my case a KVM image for Ubuntu 18.04) in which for some reason, the default in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for `AddressFamily` is set to `any` (I stumbled across this as a possibility [here on Redhat's Bugzilla platform](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1027197) after googling an error from running `journalctl -xe`, with substring `"Failed to allocate internet-domain X11 display socket."`).

The assumption of course being, that `xauth` is installed/running.

So, what can be found in the other answers here was *not* sufficient for me, I needed the settings:

```
AddressFamily inet
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

The `10` should depend on your host machine's configuration, I had to use `X11UseLocalhost no`, because otherwise the KVM guest would try to forward to its own displays, not the host machine's displays.

If you are using `ssh-agent`, then there is

```
AllowAgentForwarding yes
```

as well, which probably should be activated.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason:

**no space left on device (df shows 0 bytes)**

Possible fix: e.g. removing python-pip cache.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: This is true, no space left on device can be a reason of .Xauthority file issues.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue:

I opened an ssh connection to my server with the `-X` command option like this

```
ssh -X user@ip
```

then I got the Xauthority error. So I just ran this command on the ssh server

```
touch .Xauthority
```

Just run this

After that just

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Uncomment the following and replace `<username>` with your username

```
Match User <Username>
    X11Forwarding yes
#    AllowTcpForwarding yes
#    PermitTTY yes
#    ForceCommand cvs server
```