# ssh -X to machine without any monitor to open a GUI?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, xauth

I have two VMs running (One Ubuntu 20.04, one Fedora 30) and would like to open Firefox there. None of them has any kind of display attached. Never had.

Both are fresh and it doesn't matter much to me which can do it, but I somewhat struggle with the tutorials.

Here's the Ubuntu:

```
$ ssh ubuntu2004 -X
Last login: Sat Dec  5 07:40:17 2020 from 172.20.0.6
/usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/qohelet/.Xauthority does not exist
```

I tried to solve this issue with [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/941244/465489), but I'm not really sure if my result was supposed to happen:

```
qohelet@ubuntu2004:~$ ls .Xauthority
.Xauthority
qohelet@ubuntu2004:~$ mv .Xauthority old.Xauthority 
qohelet@ubuntu2004:~$ touch ~/.Xauthority
qohelet@ubuntu2004:~$ xauth generate :0 . trusted 
No protocol specified
xauth: (argv):1:  unable to open display ":0".
```

This issue seems to have happened to several users, but so far none of them provided a solution.
At this step I'm able to open firefox on the remote machine, on my local one the GUI pops up.

The .Xauthority is a binary file and I can't make much sense of it:

```
^@^@^@^D^?^@^A^A^@^B10^@^RMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1^@^P<9D><F4><F8>S<AE><<EB><D2>L^Q^Ns^P^G<E3><90>
```

At this point I wonder if any additional configuration was supposed to be done.
Is this good now?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to export your DISPLAY variable? example if you are IP address is 10.0.1.2:

#export DISPLAY=10.0.1.2:0.0
#xclock

otherwise maybe use MobaXterm ?